# Form credentials redirect to basic auth

Tags: php, redirect, basic-authentication

I have site1.com there are basic auth form with user and pass
site2.com have basic auth. 
When user submit his pass and user name in site1.com, i need redirect them to site2.com without promting basic auth credentials as they just enter them on site1.com

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['http_logged'] != 1) {

    }
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])|| !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ) {    
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Good day"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

echo "<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>";
echo "<h1>Authorization Required</h1>";

$_SESSION['http_logged'] = 1;
exit;

    } else {
$credentials=$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'].":".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']; 
header('Location: site2.com');
header("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials));

$_SESSION['http_logged'] = 0;
    }
?>
```

I have 2 problems:
1. When user press cancel and after return to page thebasic auth form does not showing anymore only after restart browser
2. The credential sending to site2.com does not enter site2.com as authorized.

That i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a client with a server. Quite frequent confusion though.

In short, **you can't tell a browser to authorize on the other site using basic auth. Period.**

Use cookies and cross-site authorization instead.